# Access submodule dependencies from root in multi-module Gradle build

Tags: gradle, dependencies, multi-module

Is there a way in the root `build.gradle` to access the dependencies declared in the subproject `build.gradle` files? I've tried the following --

```
subprojects.each { p ->
  println "subproject: ${p.name}"
  p.configurations.each { c ->
    println "  ${c}"
    c.dependencies.each { d ->
      println "    ${d}"
    }
  }
}
```

but I guess because the root `build.gradle` is getting executed first, the submodule dependency declarations haven't run yet, because all I get is:

```
subproject: foo
subproject: bar
subproject: baz
```

(I'm trying to write a multi-module `build.gradle` for building a bunch of related modules that don't know they're part of a multi-module project, or can be part of many different multi-module proejcts. My plan was to go through the submodule dependencies programmatically and add a corresponding `project` dependency to each one -- hoping to do something a little like [Pieter Niederweiser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84889/peter-niederwieser)'s [elastic-deps](https://github.com/pniederw/elastic-deps) example but without having to modify the subproject buildfiles. In a single-module project seems like Gradle is smart enough to use project dependencies to resolve the Maven/Ivy dependencies, if they overlap.)

---

**ETA:** If there's a way to declare at the top level a block of code that all subprojects will run at some point *after* they've declared their dependencies, that might do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If there's a way to declare at the top level a block of code that all subprojects will run at some point after they've declared their dependencies, that might do it.

`evaluationDependsOnChildren()` does the trick. All code that follows this method call will be evaluated after child projects have been evaluated.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I added the hack I came up with it as [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23574904/27358) and if you have time, I'd be interested in your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Since Gradle 3.2 you can simply call `ResolutionStrategy#preferProjectModules`.
https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy:preferProjectModules()